# Are there archives showing the nature of the relation between Allen Ginsberg and Communist parties/regimes?

Tags: allen-ginsberg

Allen Ginsberg was not a member of the Communist Party, but was (apparently until 1981, late in his life) a supporter of communism.
And he was indeed accused of being a communist by a political leader.

Here is a passage from a [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/apr/24/allen-ginsberg-postcard-eastern-europe-auction) article synthesizing the situation:

> Ginsberg's father was a socialist and his mother a supporter of the Communist Party, an upbringing which perhaps inspired the line in his 1956 first-person poem America: "I used to be a communist when I was a kid I'm not sorry." But by 1970, when Ginsberg was accused of being a "commie" by Donald Manes, he insisted in a letter to the New York City council member that he was not "as a matter of fact, a member of the Communist Party, nor am I dedicated to the overthrow of this or any government by violence. I am in fact a pacifist … [and] I must say that I see little difference between the armed and violent governments both communist and capitalist that I have observed."

Allen Ginsberg was an admirer of communist political figures such as Fidel Castro, and traveled to communist nations where he tried to influence socio-political situation (see [here](https://artdaily.cc/news/69709/Allen-Ginsberg-letter-on-the-failures-of-Communism-to-to-be-auctioned-by-Nate-D--Sanders-Auctions) for more information, or the Allen Ginsberg Wikipedia article).

Are there archives recovered from any Communist Party in any country, or a communist regime in the world, showing the kind of relation Allen Ginbserg had with communist institutions/authorities?